# My laravel (version 7) session variables are not accessible outside declared function on server

Tags: laravel, variables, session, server

```
This is my Controller
```

> Session variable generated in set_value function are not accessible inside
> function get_value. This code works fine on my localhost, but not
> working on server. All session related files are same as laravel
> documentation. Laravel version is 7.

```
public function set_value(Request $request){
    session_start();
    Session::put('name', 'Hello World');
}
public function get_value(){
    $data = Session::get('name');
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
}
```

Comment: try this session(['name' => 'Hello World']);

Comment: and get session value try this session('name'); and also remove session_start(); there is no need

Comment: I tried this also ...but not working. Issue is this works locally but not on server.

Comment: Thank You all for your reply. I have resolved issue...It was due to .htaccess file on server

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `save()` and remove `session_start();`

```php
 Session::put('name', 'Hello World');
 Session::save();
```

Answer (score 0):

To store data in session, you can use:

```
public function set_value(Request $request){
    $request->session()->put('name', 'Hello World');
}
```

There is also another way, through the global helper:

```
session(['name' => 'Hello World']);
```

To get the session value, you'd use:

```
Session::get('name');
```